# Having maximum of two page pdfs in a directory?

Tags: python, pdf, operating-system

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter
import os as os

listdir = os.listdir(r"C:\Users\Max12\Desktop\xml\pdfminer\UiPath\attachments\75090058\Status\Verwerking")

for file in listdir:
    if file.endswith(".pdf"):
        pdf_file_path = 'Unknown.pdf'
        file_base_name = file.replace('.pdf', '')
        pdf = PdfFileReader(file)
        pages = [0, 1] # page 1, 2
        pdfWriter = PdfFileWriter()
    else:
        pass
for page_num in pages:
    pdfWriter.addPage(pdf.getPage(page_num))

with open('{0}_subset.pdf'.format(file_base_name), 'wb') as f:
    pdfWriter.write(f)
    f.close()
```

Hi all,

I want to update pdf files in a directory to having two pages max. So updating the file in case they have two pages or more to a max of two pages. I've written the above stated code.

However, my IDE is giving the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file.py", line 16, in <module>
    pdfWriter.addPage(pdf.getPage(page_num))
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 1177, in getPage
    return self.flattenedPages[pageNumber]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.. Can any of you guys help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code will fail if a pdf file consists of only one page. Since `pdf.getNumPages()` returns the number of pages in the file you can replace `pages = [0, 1]` with `pages = range(min(2, pdf.getNumPages()))` to fix this.

Additionally, you iterate over pdf files in the directory, but then you process only the last file which is not what you want to accomplish. The second `for` loop and the `with` statement should be inside the `if` block.

Overall the following should work:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter
import os as os

istdir = os.listdir(r"C:\Users\Max12\Desktop\xml\pdfminer\UiPath\attachments\75090058\Status\Verwerking")

for file in listdir:
    if file.endswith(".pdf"):
        file_base_name = file.replace('.pdf', '')
        pdf = PdfFileReader(file)
        pages = range(min(2, pdf.getNumPages()))
        pdfWriter = PdfFileWriter()

        for page_num in pages:
            pdfWriter.addPage(pdf.getPage(page_num))

        with open('{0}_subset.pdf'.format(file_base_name), 'wb') as f:
            pdfWriter.write(f)
            f.close()
```

Comment: Thank you for your response bb1! Helped me a great bunch. Would you know how to write the code such that the files get updated instead of writing to new files?

Comment: Thank you I have it, simply putting file in your solution as with does the trick. Thank you!